# Change of domain deleted data in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs, windowsdomainaccount

Maybe my google-fu is failing me, but I cannot seem to find any information on the following:

My Windows user account was recently moved, accidentally, to another domain in my company's Active Directory.  While in the other domain, I was unable to access my data stored in TFS 2008 (e.g. shelvesets, pending changes, workspaces, etc).  I assume this was because it was associated with my ORIGINALDOMAIN\userId account, rather than NEWDOMAIN\userID account.

My account has now been moved back to ORIGINALDOMAIN, however I still cannot see any of my data in TFS.  In fact, it appears that all of my data (all my shelvesets!) have been deleted.  It is almost as if TFS saw that my userId had disappeared from ORIGINALDOMAIN and assumed that I had been "deleted" and thus deleted all my data.

Has anybody else encountered this?  Is there hope for my data or am I royally stuffed?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Update: I have now managed to track down some of my old shelvesets by doing a search for "*".  Oddly, the shelvesets are now associated with NEWDOMAIN\userId.  If I do an explicit search for shelvesets belonging to NEWDOMAIN\userId (or ORIGINALDOMAIN\userId) nothing is found.  Still no trace of my pending changes or workspaces though...

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I have (partially) got to the bottom of the problem.  It appears that my data has been assigned to a user id of the form DOMAIN\userid:number, instead of simply DOMAIN/userid as might be expected.

This means that I can now find my shelvesets by searching for the fully qualified id.  I still don't see any solution for resurrecting my previous pending changes or workspaces, however at least I can now retrieve the shelvesets back into my correct id.

Panic over for now.